# The order of my JS Objects appears to have changed when passing to EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

New to SO but have a question that is stumping me. I'm writing a trivia app in Node.js using Express, Mongoose and EJS. I'm running into an odd problem - or perhaps a simple one and I can't see it. I've got an EJS template that is designed to render a summary for each question to show how many times its been answered correctly and or incorrectly.

I query and return results in App.js and then send them over to the EJS template in the render statement.

Before I pass the objects to the EJS template they are in the proper order. When I start to iterate them in EJS they are no longer in order.

Here is the code in my app.js (route) for the reporting page:

```
app.get("/report", function(req, res) {
  Question.find({}, function(err, allQuestion) {
    Question.countDocuments({}, function(err, surveyQCount) {
      res.render("quesReport", {
        allQuestion,
        surveyQCount
      });
    });
  });
 });
```

When I use a colsole.log to see the order of the allQuestion result it is in the following order:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

but when I log the same allQuestion when in the EJS template it now shows as:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9]

Strange. Any idea what might be happening or where I could start to look would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please share your ejs template so i can help you out.

Comment: After some additional review, it turns out that the array is properly ordered. I was inserting some garbage inside the EJS. It's now correct. Thanks for the offer of assistance.